# Spring Boot, how to configure spring security using application.proerties

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I Have the following Security Configuration

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.servlet.configuration.EnableWebMvcSecurity;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/inspinia/login.html", "/inspinia/css/**", "/inspinia/js/**", "/inspinia/fonts/**", "/inspinia/font-awesome/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }
}
```

And I wanted to know if it is possible to set these options in application.properties instead of the WebSecurity Class.

I am new to spring and am a bit confused why some settings go in application.properties and others have to be defined in classes.

Comment: Here's a list of what can be configured properties/yaml file. http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html. Look for Security Properties and you see what you're able to configure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking I would recommend only using the application.properties to adjust Spring Security settings to get up and running fast. Once you add `WebSecurityConfig` place all your security configuration in there.

Anything you can do with application.properties you can do in Java Configuration (i.e. WebSecurityConfig).